# Software Update doesn't show available updates

Tags: macos, software-update

OS X 10.8.4 (although this started in 10.8.3). When running Software Update GUI (that switches to App Store), it shows no updates, although some are available (e.g. Java when this was posted originally, or Security Update or Airport Utility later). Running

```
softwareupdate --list
```

returns

```
Software Update found the following new or updated software:
       * JavaForOSX-1.0
        Java for OS X 2013-004 (1.0), 65205K [recommended]
```

and then

```
sudo softwareupdate --install JavaForOSX-1.0
```

installs the update.

I tried cleaning the Software Update cache, it didn't help.

Any ideas what may be going on and how to fix it?

Edit: the same problem with Security Update 2013-03and currently with a new update that is available -- Airport Utility.

Comment: It is a tricky question, as it is not possible to test fixes or workarounds in there are no updates available. I could start a bounty whenever there are updates available.

Comment: Is this specific to the Java update?  I ask because I understand an updated version was released a few days after the original update.

Comment: Not specific to Java, it was happening with other updates too.

Comment: What happens if you log out of the App Store (from the menu bar "Store" -> "Sign Out") and check for updates after that?

Comment: @Kent: I can't test this right now, as I already had to apply the Security Update and there are no more updates available. I will try this the next time when there is an update.

Comment: @Kent: the same thing happens regardless of whether I am logged in or not.

Comment: I wish I knew the answer, because my experience with Software Update is that it has seemed far less reliable through the Mac App Store than it was on its own. I'm running `softwareupdate --install --all` nightly via `launchd` to avoid having to worry about it.

Comment: @TJLuoma: the strange thing is that `--all` doesn't work, I have to do `softwareupdate --install update_name`.

Comment: Do you have the debug menu enabled in the MAS?

Comment: @Tortilla: yes, the debug menu is enabled and I couldn't find any errors in the log.

Answer (score 3):

This sometimes helps me when I know that there is an update: Cmd-R. Since the iTunes/iBooks/Mac App Store are all web-based, it forces a refresh.

Your problem sounds more systemic than this, but it’s a quick thing to check (especially for those Java OS X update which hide from me sometimes).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in a different of OSX and I can say there might be three possible reasons for that.

1.You might have apps installed under different accounts (Yes, you would know, probably not this one)

2.You might have apps installed from different country-appstores and changed back country.

3.You might have apps that are not originally installed from the App Store  yet now provided an update from the App Store.

(Actually this answer of mine does not provide a solution but suggests some points to start digging.)

Answer (score 0):

Okay,

Im not sure how correct this is but I have had the same problem.

Here is what I've been able to correlate. (Not sure if its true)

The app store update (GUI as you put it) pull information that your mac has installed through the app store.

It has no idea about system level updates that have taken place.

In my case, I update iPhoto manually through the pkg file and I stopped getting update notifications through the app store and yet was able to update through the command line.

The problem was fixed for me when apple sent a combo update that then reallocated my iPhoto with my app store apps.

I think this is a bug. You might want to add it to a bug report [here](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/)
They will ask for some system profiler stuff to better debug.